# installing phpunit and examples

Tags: php, phpunit

I am trying to learn PHPUnit. I use MacOS X and just installed PHPUnit using PEAR by doing this:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

After installation, it's located in `pear/share/pear/PHPUnit`. It has `Extensions` and `Framework` folders.

I tried creating the examples from the [Pear PHPUnit tutorial](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.phpunit.intro.php), but in the example it says it requires `PHPUnit.php` and I don't see that file. Do I need to install anything else to make this work?

Also, where should the example scripts be placed?

Can anyone please guide me in setting up this PHPunit test and try it with one example? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs located at the pear.phpunit.de channel are completely out of date. Please do not use them anymore. [Quoting Sebastian Bergmann](https://twitter.com/#!/s_bergmann/status/57901098131918849), author of PHPUnit:

> Whoever is responsible for the PEAR Manual: please remove http://bit.ly/gU8eEG as it confuses people (and search engines).

The official docs are located at:

- http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/index.html

To install PHPUnit, follow the instructions at the official phpunit website instead:

- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/

e.g. do

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
```

and then

```
pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
```

Comment: thanks, i see more files inside my pear/share/pear folder along with Extensions and Framework, still i cannot find that phpunit.php as in the example link i gave before..now is it possible for me to to try some small example to understand what is php unit test?

Comment: i got this example - http://blogs.sitepoint.com/tutorial-introduction-to-unit-testing-in-php-with-phpunit/ .i am able to run this one.